# in badminton double both players hit the shuttle same time

Tags: badminton

senario is like this ...in badminton double game, both players are right handed , as shuttle went in middle of both players , one player want to play slow as shuttle is in his left side and his partner get that on right side. during playin one partner wants to drop and other partner hit his racket from backside as shuttle is on his right side and shuttle went to opponent court. In this case both player play the shot at same time. is it foul?

Comment: How many rackets actually contacted the shuttle? Your title and description seem inconsistent.

Comment: That's a double-touch. The point is lost.

Comment: It’s not possible for two players to hit the shuttle at the same time, unless their racquets are on opposite sides of it, in which case they squash the shuttle between them and it won’t go anywhere. In any other situation, the physical dimensions of shuttle and racquets means that one racquet will always have hit the shuttle before the other.